# Update to reactive 18.1.0

Tags: react-native, npm, npx

I try create a react-app with **npx create-native init project** but the react version was **17.0.2**.
I used **npm install react react-dom**( following https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html) to update for the new version but now I received the message when I try create a nem project: **npm ERR! could not determine executable to run**.

What should I do?

log:

38 verbose stack **Error: could not determine executable to run**
38 verbose stack     at getBinFromManifest (C:\Users\55319\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmexec\lib\get-bin-from-manifest.js:17:23)
38 verbose stack     at exec (C:\Users\55319\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmexec\lib\index.js:135:15)
38 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Users\55319\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:78:5)
39 verbose pkgid create-native@1.0.0
40 verbose cwd C:\Users\55319
41 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
42 verbose node v16.15.0
43 verbose npm  v8.8.0
44 **error could not determine executable to run**
45 verbose exit 1
46 timing npm Completed in 2369ms
47 verbose code 1
48 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
48 error     C:\Users\55319\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-05-12T01_59_05_028Z-debug-0.log
[CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlUha.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It installed that version because that's the version it's compatible with, as of this writing (RN 68.1). React Native often doesn't use the latest version of React.  If you open up the [changelog for React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v0680) and search for React 17, you'll see it was introduced into React Native version 64.0.  There are no hits for React 18 because it hasn't yet been integrated.